# pass a GCM message from GCMService in an Android Library to an Android app which uses the Library

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-library

i have an Android library which i developed and it contains the GCM service. Everything is fine with the GCM and i get the push messages from my server. My App using this library and i need somehow to pass the messages to my app, if the app isnt running i need to wake up the app and show some notifications. i tried to register a broadcast receiver from my library and send a broadcast every time i get a new message but it doesnt work. is there any other way to implement that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you added the permissions into your app's Manifest? (**NOT** in the library project)

Comment: yeah.. i am getting the gcm messages but i want to get it inside the lib - so it will be transparent to the app and pass it to the app somehow